# MS Access Library Template - Reference Category Value in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Completely new to MS Access - I'm trying to do a simple modification to the MS Access Lending Library template using VBA.

Going into the Asset List form and clicking New Asset pops up the Asset Details form, where I can click the Save and New button. This calls the VBA code cmdSaveandNew_Click().

My question is, within this VBA method, how do I reference the values of the fields in the Asset Details form - For example getting the value that the user entered in the Category field and storing it in a variable.

I've tried several strings of code to try to get the value back, but I keep getting various errors, saying it can't find the referenced form, or Object Required, or this method is supported. I think it's likely just that I don't fully understand the structure of what I'm trying to reference or the syntax for specifying how to reference it.

Right now (after I've been trying many different combinations of things, I have:
`text = Forms![Asset List].[Asset Details].Form.Category`

which is giving me the "can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression" error.

Edit - code currently looks like this:

```
Private Sub cmdSaveandNew_Click()
'On Error GoTo cmdSaveandNew_Click_Err

Dim someVar As String
Dim num As Integer
Dim objtf
'objtf = Forms![Asset List].[Asset Details].Form.Category
objtf = Me.Category
'num = Form.Controls.Count
Msg.Box (TypeName(objtf))

someVar = InputBox("How many?")



On Error Resume Next
If (Form.Dirty) Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
If (MacroError.Number <> 0) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
DoCmd.GoToControl "Item"


MsgBox someVar


cmdSaveandNew_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdSaveandNew_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdSaveandNew_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.

Comment: Rats! The version of LendingLibrary I have uses macros. Did you convert to VBA? The variable must be declared global in a general module if you want to reference from various modules. Then setting it by code behind the Asset Details form would be simply: `SomeVariableName = Me.Category`. Don't use reserved words as names - `text` is a reserved word.

Comment: @June7 Yes, I converted to VBA because to be honest, I don't really understand how to control what macros do. I'll update the post to show what my code now looks like - but doing the Me.Category now generates a "Object Required" error.

Comment: @June7 UPDATE - Just realized I'd put a . in the middle of Msgbox for some reason. The Me.Category code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable must be declared global in a general module if you want to reference from various modules. Then setting it by code behind the Asset Details form would be simply: `SomeVariableName = Me.Category`.

Don't use reserved words as names - text is a reserved word.